# Run a second query inside a foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, foreach

Need to run 2 queries inside a foreach but cant do it without errors.

So, i have this for showing comments:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM comments WHERE updatepostid = "' . $postID . '"';
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $countcomments = $stmt->rowCount();
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex) 
        {
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
        }

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows as $row):
$commentID       = $row['commentID'];
$usercommentID   = $row['userID'];
$commentusername = ucfirst($row['commentusername']);
$comment         = ucfirst($row['comment']);
$updatepostid    = $row['updatepostid'];

<div class="textcomment">
    <?php
        echo "<a class='$rightscommentcolor'>$commentusername:</a>&nbsp; $comment";
    ?>
</div>


<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I then however want to run another query on the users database to check what rights the user has and then set the class of the comments username to that class.

That query would be e.g.

```
    <?php

$query2 = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = "' . $usercommentID . '"';
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query2);
        $stmt->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex) 
        {
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
        }

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows as $row):
$rights = $row['rights'];

if ($rights = '1') {
    $rightscommentcolor = 'userrights1';
} else if ($rights = '5') {
    $rightscommentcolor = 'userrights5';
}

?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

How is the proper way to go about this?

P.S. i understand that the above code will probably make people cry.

Comment: In your first sql statement you need to `JOIN` the `comments` and `users` tables so that you only need to query the database once: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can join the tables in select as mentioned:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM comments c
          JOIN users u ON u.usercommentID = c.userID
          WHERE updatepostid = :updatepostid";
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $countcomments = $stmt->rowCount();
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex) 
        {
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
        }

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows as $row):

$commentID       = $row['commentID'];
$usercommentID   = $row['userID'];
$commentusername = ucfirst($row['commentusername']);
$comment         = ucfirst($row['comment']);
$updatepostid    = $row['updatepostid'];

if ($rights = '1') {
    $rightscommentcolor = 'userrights1';
} else if ($rights = '5') {
    $rightscommentcolor = 'userrights5';
}

echo "<div class="textcomment"><a class='$rightscommentcolor'>$commentusername:</a>&nbsp; $comment</div>";

endforeach;

?>
```

You also could insert the second loop within the first and assign separate variables to that second loop so that it does not conflict with the first as below, but joining would be a better option:

```
<?php

$query = 'SELECT * FROM comments WHERE updatepostid = "' . $postID . '"';
    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $countcomments = $stmt->rowCount();
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex) 
        {
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
        }

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows as $row):

$commentID       = $row['commentID'];
$usercommentID   = $row['userID'];
$commentusername = ucfirst($row['commentusername']);
$comment         = ucfirst($row['comment']);
$updatepostid    = $row['updatepostid'];

$query2 = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE usercommentID = "' . $usercommentID . '"';
    try {
        $stmt2 = $db->prepare($query2);
        $stmt2->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex2) 
        {
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex2->getMessage());
        }

$rows2 = $stmt2->fetchAll();
foreach ($rows2 as $row2):
$rights = $row2['rights'];

if ($rights = '1') {
    $rightscommentcolor = 'userrights1';
} else if ($rights = '5') {
    $rightscommentcolor = 'userrights5';
}

endforeach;

echo "<div class="textcomment"><a class='$rightscommentcolor'>$commentusername:</a>&nbsp; $comment</div>";

endforeach;

?>
```

Comment: Using the last one for now as it works a treat :)

Shall try to change it a JOIN statement if its possible :)

Answer (score 4):

Use a single query with a join. Also, since you're using PDO, you should use parametrized queries rather than concatenating strings.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM comments c
          JOIN users u ON u.id = c.userID
          WHERE updatepostid = :updatepostid";
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array(':updatepostid' => $postID));
    }
catch (PDOException $ex) 
    {
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: have tried using this but am getting the same issue before where its no errors, but seems to be killing the page. My error handler seems to not be working and not displaying any errors, when removing the die() the rest of the page loads.

I have also changed the query2 to query but no change.

Comment: I don't see how that could be. If it's going into the `catch` block, then it should display the message when it dies.

Comment: I had a typo in my answer, `$query2` instead of `$query`. If you copied it, try fixing that.

Comment: got the errors displaying right now, mamp was being funny.

Ill come back when i have narrowed down any issues my side :)

Comment: Sorry, just ammended the question. I dont have usercommentID in the users table.

Comment: Then replace it with whatever the actual column name is.