# In PHP how can I play audio from a database in a foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql, audio, pdo, foreach

I have audio stored in a database which I would like to be posted as audio objects on a message board. There is already one SQL query in which I join PostImages and forumPosts which I then echo out in a foreach loop. I have attempted to initiate a second SQL query in the foreach loop for display of audio but it doesn't work. When uncommenting the second query I get 'Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]' with that error being at the execute statement. There is a posting about placing a second query inside a foreach loop here: [Run a second query inside a foreach loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19778169/run-a-second-query-inside-a-foreach-loop) If my approach is wrong I would love constructive ideas.

A previous posting on stackoverflow explained I need to have `base64_encode($statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN))` in order to get the audio to play. I tried to look up `(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)` but couldn't get a clear understanding of what it does or whether I need it or should use something else. That post is here: [how to play mp3 audio stored im mysql blob using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35623814/how-to-play-mp3-audio-stored-im-mysql-blob-using-php)

In the code below I echo out a table to contain images and audio. I have commented out the parts of the second query which are not working. I have `if` statements to determine if an image or audio should be posted. I hope this is clear. I can add more information if necessary. PLEASE if someone could help. I have been as complete as possible with my posting and I have worked really hard on this! I am just trying to figure out this hurdle.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM forumPosts LEFT JOIN PostImages ON 
forumPosts.DATETIME = PostImages.ImageDATETIME ORDER BY replyIndex 
ASC';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$posts = $statement->fetchAll();

$statement->closeCursor();
echo "<table>"; 
 foreach ($posts as $post){
     if ($post['post_type'] == "r"){

        $post_id = $post['post_id'];

        echo "<tr bgcolor='beige'><td>". $post['post_title'] ."</td >
        <td>". $post['post_body']; 

        if (!empty($post['ID']) && ($post['type']== 'i')) {

            echo "<img src='getImage.php?id=".$post['ID']."'>";
            } elseif (!empty($post['ID']) && ($post['type']== 'm')) {

            //$query2 = 'SELECT* FROM from forumPosts WHERE post_id 
            ='.$post['post_id']; 
            //$statement2 = $db->prepare($query2);
            //$statement2->execute();

            echo '<div content="Content-Type: audio/mp3"><audio 
            controls="controls" preload="metadata" autoplay>

            <source 
    src="data:audio/mp3;base64,'.base64_encode
    ($statement2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)).'"/>;</audio></div>';
    }
```

Comment: Hello, You are saved audio in audio format or audio name in database ?

Comment: Unless you start listen to what you are told, you are bound to delete and re-ask your question again and again. Howe many times you did it already? Five?

Comment: Yes I have audio saved as an mp3 in my database.

Comment: I have stated a very succinct issue I am having with displaying audio. This person is trolling me when I honestly need help. Please give me ideas on how to proceed with this issue.

Comment: @YourCommonSense didn't ruin anything for you. No one answered this question for who knows what reason, not because of his comment or his down-vote. Please read [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers) for what you should do now. Note that the link does not suggest ranting in your comments, and I would personally advise against this, since this results in a much greater risk of this gathering down-votes and de-motivating us from answer it, much more than YCS's comment. Best of luck, and hope you get a decent answer soon.

Comment: There was absolutely nothing the matter with my post. The troll who has followed me cited no particular instance of wrong-doing and definitely offered nothing constructive. It has been over a week with no responses due to this cursed person. You will notice the last time I received any insight was just before he posted. I don't know where else to go! I am begging for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was right in my face the whole time. Because I was already in a foreach loop for a query that included the joined images table I didn't have to query a second time. I already had the code that checked for an 'm' for mp3. I just had to echo out the controls for audio object with the $posts['image'] there to grab the audio from my database.

```
elseif (!empty($post['ID']) && ($post['type']== 'm')) {
    echo '<audio controls>'; 
    echo '<source
    src="data:audio/mp3;base64,'.base64_encode($post['image']).'"‌​>';
    echo '</audio>';
    }
```